Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{{\cos(x)^{n}(1-\cos{x})^2}\, dx}$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{{\cos(x)^{n}(1-\cos{x})^2}\, dx}$$
From Fubini's theorem, I switched the order of Summation and Integration. Then it becomes
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{(1-\cos{x})^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\cos(x)^{n}} 
dx}$
The series is Geometric and converges to
$\frac{-1}{\cos{x}-1}$ since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{n}{x}=0$
So finally we have
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{(1-\cos{x})^2\frac{-1}{\cos{x}-1} dx}$=$\frac{\pi}{2}-1$
Is my course of action correct?

Looks good, but I don't understand why you need $\lim (\cos x)^n=0$, to apply the geometric series you need $|\cos x|<1$
